# Casting a long int to void *

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, posix

Is this the correct way of casting a `long` to `void *`? I'm getting a segfault when using `-O2` in a `Qt` program. It does not segfault when using `-O1`.

When using `reinterpret_cast<void *>(tp.tv_nsec)` I also get a segfault using `-O2`.

Why is there a segfault?

```
timespec tp; // struct that holds nanoseconds since Epoch
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp); // tv_nsec is a long int

void *test = mmap((void *)(tp.tv_nsec), 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

printf("%p\n", test);
printf("%li\n", (long)test);
```

**EDIT:** AFAIK, the objective seems to have been expressed wrong. The objective is to get a random number in order to allocate a random memory address. That way I will get a random memory address every time I feed mmap() a random number the many times I use mmap() throughout my test program. If not, mmap() seems to allocate memory rather sequentially.

Comment: What does the current time have to do with an address?

Comment: Wh-wh-what on earth are you trying to do? Whether this seg-faults or not would depend on exactly when you run it, regardless of whether you have -O1 or -O2. But I fail to see the purpose - are you trying to see if `mmap` is implemented secureley so that if you take a `random` address and feed it in, it will do the right thing, or why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not wondering why you cast a variable into an address variable but one of your optimization settings are against this:

-O2 turns on all optimization flags specified by -O. It also turns on the following optimization flags:

```
      -fthread-jumps 
      -falign-functions  -falign-jumps 
      -falign-loops  -falign-labels 
      -fcaller-saves 
      -fcrossjumping 
      -fcse-follow-jumps  -fcse-skip-blocks 
      -fdelete-null-pointer-checks 
      -fdevirtualize 
      -fexpensive-optimizations 
      -fgcse  -fgcse-lm  
      -fhoist-adjacent-loads 
      -finline-small-functions  ----------> Result: this is causing the segfault(elaine has found so +1 to him please).
      -findirect-inlining 
      -fipa-sra 
      -foptimize-sibling-calls 
      -fpartial-inlining 
      -fpeephole2 
      -fregmove 
      -freorder-blocks  -freorder-functions 
      -frerun-cse-after-loop  
      -fsched-interblock  -fsched-spec 
      -fschedule-insns  -fschedule-insns2 
      -fstrict-aliasing                 --------> I thought this was issue(void * from long) but is not
      -fstrict-overflow 
      -ftree-switch-conversion -ftree-tail-merge 
      -ftree-pre 
      -ftree-vrp
```

I suspected:

-fstrict-aliasing
Allow the compiler to assume the strictest aliasing rules applicable to the language being compiled. For C (and C++), this activates optimizations based on the type of expressions. In particular, an object of one type is assumed never to reside at the same address as an object of a different type, unless the types are almost the same. For example, an unsigned int can alias an int, but not a void* or a double. A character type may alias any other type.

I was wrong, shame on me.

```
 >:c
```

**According to what elaine said, -finline-small-functions is source of the problem.**

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Actually, the segfault was with `-finline-small-functions`. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

casting is not valid because `tp.tv_nsec` is not an address:

```
mmap((void *)(tp.tv_nsec), 4096,
                 ^ 
                 |  is not an address
```

Try this:

```
mmap((void *) &(tp.tv_nsec), 4096,
              ^
              |  amperson operator for address
```

`&` is Address (of operand) operator gives address of a variable

Comment: Whilst this does indeed give an address, I doubt very much it's a useful address to give to `mmap`, since it's supposed to be an UNUSED region of memory. I fail to see how this code could be useful for ANYTHING other than an alternative to `mmap((void *)rand(), ...)` - which is also useless.

Comment: @Mats Petersson No really. That is only the case with MAP_FIXED. See my comment for Jens Gustedt.

Answer (score 0):

With construction `reinterpret_cast<void *>(tp.tv_nsec)` you are taking **long** and interpret it as a pointer. This cause to wrong memory access. You should take its **address** and cast it into `void*`: `reinterpret_cast<void *>(&tp.tv_nsec)`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is for C, but I suppose that for C++ is similar. Conversion from integer types to pointer is not guaranteed to work in all cases, since they may have different width and pointers may be segmented. If there is an integer type for which this works on your platform, it should be `typedef`ed to `[u]intptr_t`, so if you have to do such cruft, use that type.

Then you are using `mmap` with something that is not at all foreseen to be done like that. If you pass it an address it is your duty to verify that this is a valid address in your address space to use for that. E.g it must be a multiple of a page size, but other restrictions may apply. Check the return value of the `mmap` call to see if it succeeded.

For a start it would probably be good to read the documentation that comes with your system. `man mmap` is your friend.

Comment: [mmap()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) "A non-zero value of addr is taken to be a suggestion of a process address near which the mapping should be placed."